# Change the enum index value from database in javascript file [Laravel]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

In my Laravel website I am retrieving values from database table `marketplace_trades` which has `enum` type data in it. in `js` file I am trying to change this value and make different color. I was able to make it in different color but don't have any idea how to change `enum` value. The exact field in database is like below :

```
$table->enum('status', [
                'active', 'successful', 'cancelled', 'dispute'
            ])->default('active');
```

in my js file where I am calling it is :

```
dataIndex : 'status',
                render    : (status) => (
                    <Tag color={this.getStatusColor(status)}>
                        {upperFirst(status)}
```

Everything is great. The only thing I have to do is change the word "active" to "Active Trades" (for example) and make the user see this word like this. It is needed because of multilingual option of the website. can I make `if` query in `js` file and attach new value on it ?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: putting down full js code :

```
getStatusColor = (status) => {
        switch (status) {
            case 'successful':
                return "#52c41a";
            case 'active':
                return "#2db7f5";
            case 'dispute':
                return "#faad14";
            case "cancelled":
                return "#f5222d";
            default :
                return null;
        }
    };

    columns = () => {
        return [
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Coin"
                        id="common.coin"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'coin_name',
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Amount"
                        id="common.amount"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'formatted_amount_price',
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Seller"
                        id="common.seller"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'seller',
                render    : (seller) => (
                    <UserTableCell user={seller}/>
                )
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Buyer"
                        id="common.buyer"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'buyer',
                render    : (buyer) => (
                    <UserTableCell user={buyer}/>
                )
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Status"
                        id="common.status"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'status',
                render    : (status) => (
                    <Tag color={this.getStatusColor(status)}>
                        {upperFirst(status)}
                    </Tag>
                )
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Rate"
                        id="common.rate"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'formatted_rate',
            },
            {
                title     : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Payment Method"
                        id="common.payment_method"/>
                ),
                dataIndex : 'payment_method_name',
                render : (payment_method_name, record) => (
                    <div style={{whiteSpace : 'nowrap'}}>
                        <span className="mr-2">
                            {payment_method_name}
                        </span>
                        {record.payment_method_description && (
                            <Popover overlayStyle={{maxWidth : 250}}
                                     content={record.payment_method_description}
                                     title={
                                         <FormattedMessage
                                             id="common.payment_method_description"
                                             defaultMessage="Description"/>
                                     }
                                     trigger="click">
                                <Icon type="question-circle" theme="filled"/>
                            </Popover>
                        )}
                    </div>
                )
            },
            {
                title  : (
                    <FormattedMessage
                        defaultMessage="Action"
                        id="common.action"/>
                ),
                key    : 'action',
                fixed  : 'right',
                render : (text, record) => {
                    return (
                        <Button type="primary"
                                onClick={(e) => this.goToChat(record.chat_id)}
                                icon="link"/>
                    );
                },
            },
        ];
    };
```

Comment: Change with JS is better than change on table column

Comment: I don't want to change the structure what I have at the moment. I am trying to change it in JS side and attain new value and show users.

Comment: `if(status == 'active') { 'Active Trades' }`

Comment: I tried this but I think I am putting this incorrect place : `dataIndex : 'status', render: status) => (<Tag color={this.getStatusColor(status)}>
{upperFirst(status)}    if(status == 'active') { 'Active Trades' } </Tag>`

when I try like this it gets `if` as a text. I see the text : `Activeif(status == 'active') Active Trades`. Tried to put at the top again same.

Comment: `if(status == 'active') { 'Active Trades' }` not works no matter where I put.. will get crazy :)

Comment: maybe create a new function like `getStatusColor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with React, but I think you need to do that like this :

```js
getStatusName = (status) => {
        switch (status) {
            case 'successful':
                return "Successfull";
            case 'active':
                return "Active Trades";
            case 'dispute':
                return "Dispute";
            case "cancelled":
                return "Cancelled";
            default :
                return null;
        }
    };
```

And render it like this way :

```
render    : (status) => (
   <Tag color={this.getStatusColor(status)}>
       {this.getStatusName(status)}
  </Tag>
 )
```